# Unknown class CustomUITableViewCell in Interface Builder file xcode 8

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitableview

I try to create a custom UITableViewCell in my project. In another project it's work fine, but in the current, I have an error.

> Unknown class DetailsMYFRiendsTableView in Interface Builder file

The first thing I do is to check in Storyboard, but I can't add a module !

[image: Error xcode]

When I try to select, no module is available, If I try to add manually my project name ( ex : My Project ) it's not working, If I try with : My_Project it's not working too.

Another thing I try is to edit Storyboard with the source code and adding this line :

```
customModule="AppName" customModuleProvider="target"
```

But I have the same error, always.

This a my class declaration in my ViewController :

```
class DetailsFriendsViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {
... Some code
}
class DetailsMYFRiendsTableView: UITableViewCell {

        @IBOutlet var city: UILabel!
        @IBOutlet var gps: UILabel!
        @IBOutlet var date: UILabel!
    }
```

Comment: Are you sure `DetailsMYFRiendsTableView` exisits? - doesn't sound like a `tableViewCell` to me.

Comment: Yes, I edited my post. Class exist and is on the same viewcontroller than the tableview

Comment: try to clean the project and run again.

Comment: @SurjeetSinghRajput, already done, same result

Comment: My Project Name is : My Project, maybe the error is the blank space between My and Project ??

Comment: upload your project ..

Answer (score 1):

Check your compiled source, whether that file(e.g; ViewController.m) is added or not.

Comment: My ViewController is present

Answer (score 0):

```
 Target --> Build Phases --> Compile Sources
```

Check if your file exists here. If not then add it here then clean, build and run your project.

Comment: I resolved my problem by creating my custom class in a specific file, and now it's working !